# How to (properly) export a Form and its resources (such as images) as an Item template?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, templates

I'm using **VisualStudio 2013** and I would like to export as an **VS Item template** a Form that I've written.

I'm using 4 custom images (local resources on disk):

[image]

Of course I need to export the images (is the first time that I try to export resources in a template) and the problem begins when I create the Item template:

[image]

Then I create a new project to test my new Item template:

[image]

but when I try to load my Item template which is suppossed to have the Form and "*All dependandt files including resource files*" the resources are not included and I get these errors:

[image]

(In the designer file:)

```
Me.ToolStripButton_SendToClipboard.Image = Global.TestSolution.My.Resources.Resources.Clipboard
```

> Clipboard is not a member of TestSolution.My.Resources.Resources

( note in the error message that the 'Resources' namespace is written 2 times... yes )

...And so on with the other 3 images.

So What can I do?

I would like to have my '*ErrorDialog*' Form portabilized, just to load it as an Item template in any kind of project without be worried about those resources.

PS: The exported 'ErrorDialog.resx" table file does not contains any of the four images, and I don't know how to add them manually orelse whether it's possible to do it manually in the resx table inside the **.ZIP** template.

> UPDATE

I've tried to unzip the zipped template to do manual changes (to be able to load the fuc**ing images) then I've copied/pasted in the Root dir of the template solution the "Resources" folder that contains the 4 images so I have this folder '**C:\VS Item templates\My Item Template\Resources**', then after that I did this changes in the designer:

From this:

```
Me.ToolStripButton_SendToClipboard.Image = Global.$rootnamespace$.My.Resources.Clipboard
```

To this else:

```
Me.ToolStripButton_SendToClipboard.Image = Image.FromFile(".\Resources\Clipboard.png")
```

That I was supposed that the relative path should points to '**C:\VS Item templates\My Item Template\Resources**', but don't, the relative path is searching in the working directory of the project where I load the item template, for example if I create a new project in '**C:\VS Projects\MyProject\Solution.sl**' and I load the item template in design time then the images are searched in '**C:\VS Projects\MyProject\Resources\Image.png**', so the '**.\Resources**' that I've specified is not searching the image in the root folder of the item template.

Maybe that could be fixed specifying any kind of VS global variable in the relative path above?.

( that was a close enough intent )

> UPDATE 2

Here is the source if someone could check how to export the Dialog as an Item template with images included ...really thankyou.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/f6caca6bcc9wbwc/Elektro+ErrorDialog.rar

Comment: a) the resource export portion is not wrong.  they mean that the form's resx file will be included, not the **project** resources.  How would that work when you add a template to a Project?  Replace the existing Resource Folder?  merge?  b) add the images to the form in an Imagelist and they will stay with the form  c) even if it worked I dont think you want to use a Global macro because you'd have to have a Resources folder deployed as well.  d) why not just add your custom Dialog to a DLL and use it thru a class?

Comment: @Plutonix a) Would be great that the exporting/importing mechanism detects the resources used by the element to export, and then when importing it merges the project resources (my.resources.resx) to add the resources of the imported element, is not a crazy idea for me ...would be the best, but ok I understand that it's not possible. b) Do you mean to set an imagelist object (from code, in the form class)? in that case I've tried it, but it doesn't stay in the exported form (of course the code stays, but the images not).

Comment: c) I think that I've ddidn't understood good what you've said in this point but I've deployed the "Resources" folder containing the images, the folder is in the root dir of the exported Item (C:\Item Templates\My Dialog\Resources) so really I think that I've all the necessary things deployed but the problem is that I can't find the way to "determine" the root folder of the imported form to load those deployed resources when importing the form...and maybe with the help of an (unknown) global variable I could determinate the root folder. d) I've tried it with no luck,maybe I did something wrong

Comment: a) I agree it would be nice, but there is a diff between FORM res. and PRJ res. and you are exporting a FORM item b) Use an ImgList component in the Dialog form to hold the images (from toolbox using the form tray, not a code instance).  It works (tested). c) If you have code relying on an image in a ?/Resources folder, you will have to have that on runtime installs which seems undesirable.  d)  maybe - a DLL implementation would allow you to skip the imagelist and pull imgs from Prj Resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are exporting a **Form** item while the images are in **Project** Resources.  As a result, the images are not there.  The export process doesnt work like Code Analysis and run the code to see what you **might** assign to it; it relies on "static" references in the RESX file.

The solution is to get the images into the form RESX by adding an ImageList component (its not a control) and adding the desired images to it.  This way, they are stored **in** the form's resx as shown here:

```
<data name="ImageList1.ImageStream" 
         mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
 <value>
    AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvb
    LCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPWI3N2E1YzU2MTkzNGUwODkFA
    ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3Jtcy5JbWFnZUxpc3RTdHJlYW1lcgEAAAAERGF0YQcCAgAAAAkDA
    (etc)
```

This should then export fine to a template, but I should think the DLL approach is much more suitable to what you are doing.