# How to (properly) use this VisualStudio global variable?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've exported an Item template that depends on some local images, and I would like to load them manually 'cause if I don't load them I get exceptions.

I'm trying to use the global variable [$(ProjectDir)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) in the `Form.Designer.vb` but seems that is not recognized, what I'm doing wrong?

```
Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("$(ProjectDir)\Resources\Clipboard.png")
```

When I load the item template, the string above is read as a literal String.

PS: Also I don't know whether the global variable would points to the path of the solution where I'm loading my item template, or would points to the path where ive exported my item template... of course I need the second thing.

Note that I've marked this question with C# 'cause the usage of the global variables should be the same...

Comment: Have you read just the title of the article link to which you have provided?

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan I've suppossed that those vars could be used in this way too, 'cause for example $(rootnamespace) global variable is in the link, and a $rootnamespace$ variable is autogenerated in each file... seems the same, if not then I'm wrong and that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Consider editning title/tags to be "can I use MSBuild variables in C# code"... Note that what your sample is showing is duplicate of many "how to load file from resource folder in C#".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are not approaching the problem correctly. First `$(ProjectDir)` is a macro used by Visual Studio IDE for getting project's current path. If you want to get that through code then you can do:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.FullName, 
                               "Resources\\Clipboard.png");
```

But more importantly you **have them in Resources**. Why not use WinForm resources for it. You can add the image in resources, These resources will be available with the build and you can access them through code like:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Clipboard.png;
```

See: [How to add images as resources to C# Windows Application](http://dotnetdud.blogspot.ca/2009/01/how-to-add-resources-to-c-windows.html)

Comment: +0: CurrentDirectory is likely bad idea - $(ProjectDir) is close to ExecutingAssembly...

Comment: @Habb thanks for your help but the things that you've mentioned about the resources are uncertain, you can see my principal problem here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431702/how-to-properly-export-a-form-and-its-resources-such-as-images-as-an-item-te , when exporting as an item template the resources are not exported then I've copied manually the 'Resources' folder in the item template root and now I'm messing up my head to be able to get the root dir of the loaded template to load the images... but no way, there is no way for me.

Comment: Also when I use 'CurrentDirectory' method in the File.designer.vb it points to the dir where I've installer the VS IDE (devenv.exe), I've tried also with reflection but with no luck.

Comment: Anyways the question about the usage of that macros is solved so thanks

Comment: @ElektroStudios, You can specify the resource type in Persistence - Embedded with resx, and then it would be available with the application, irrespective of the path.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, may be `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` would be the correct one ?

Comment: @Habib I've followed the steps that you've said (Persistence - Embedded with resx), but the resulting .resx table inside the zipped Item template does not contains any of the images. In my project (a Winforms) I have two forms, I only want to export one form which is using images from My.Resources namespace. please if you could help here or in the post that I've said... really thankyou

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I am not really sure what you mean by `only want to export one form which is using images from My.Resources namespace. `

Comment: @Habib If I give you the url containing the (tiny) source you could consider to check what I've say and try to export the Form as an Item template?. What I mean is that I've put 4 images and I access to them like `My.Resources.ImageName1`, I just note that 'cause I don't know if that could be the problem... so in the Form that I want to export I do: `Control.Property = My.Resources.ImageName1`, and when I try to export the form as an item template it looses the images and the `Form.Designer.vb` file has this: `Me.ControlName.Image = Global.$rootnamespace$.My.Resources.ImageName1`.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, shouldn't you be doing `Control.Property = Properties.Resources.ImageName1`

Comment: I didn't understood that, sorry, this is how it's written before exporting this form (in the **Form.Designer.vb**): `Me.ControlName.Image = Global.ErrorDialog.My.Resources.ImageName`

Comment: Anyways here is the source if someone else wants to help to solve this: http://www.mediafire.com/download/f6caca6bcc9wbwc/Elektro_ErrorDialog.rar (I've uploaded this before doing the 'Persistence - Embedded with resx' step)

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I was able to open your project, and compile successfully `PictureBox_Error.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Clipboard`, the only problem with your resources is they are not set to be as Embedded Resource. Go to MyProject -> Resources.resx, double click it, it will open the designer. From there on the top select Images, click on the Clipboard Image, and go  to its properties, there set Persistence.

Comment: +1. Yes, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is better mapping to `$(ProjectDir)` (there are other ways to get the same/similar "executable path" too).

Comment: @Habib soory but I think you don't understood, of course the solution can be open and compiled, the problem is that I can't export that form as an Item template (file > export template) including those images even doing the 'persistence' thing (and also setting the build actions as 'embedded resource'). but really thanks for tried it!

Answer (score 1):

The variable you're using is not for use in code, only for macros within visual studio (like pre-build events).

See this question for information regarding getting the project directory:
[How to get Current Project Directory path using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218776/how-to-get-current-project-directory-path-using-c-sharp)